# Code First Many to Many query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a code table:

```
public class Code
{
    [Key]
    public int CodeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Project { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string CMS { get; set; }

    public int DotNetVersion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Dependencies { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string CodeFile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string TFSLocation { get; set; }

    ////Creates a relationship in the DB with Tag
    //[ForeignKey("TagID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    ////Purely for API
    //[Required]
    public int TagID { get; set; }
}
```

A tag table:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    ////Creates a relationship in the DB with Code
    public virtual ICollection<Code> Code { get; set; }
}
```

And a view model:

```
public class CodeTagViewModel
{
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> SelectedTags { get; set; }        

    public int CodeID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string CMS { get; set; }
    public int DotNetVersion { get; set; }
    public string Dependencies { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string CodeFile { get; set; }
    public string TFSLocation { get; set; }

}
```

And I'm trying to run a query to get code files that are linked to tag names that have been searched. At the moment I have something like this:

```
        List<CodeTagViewModel> models = new List<CodeTagViewModel>();
        List<Code> codes = db.Code.ToList<Code>();

        foreach (Code code in codes)
        {
            models.Add(MapCodeToModel(code));
        }

        var orderedModels = models.ToList();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            orderedModels = models.Where(x => x.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || x.Description.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || x.Project.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || x.CMS.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || x.Dependencies.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || x.Author.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).ToList();

            if(orderedModels.Count == 0)
            {
                var Tags = db.Tags;
                 orderedModels = models.SelectMany(x => x.SelectedTags).Select(t => t).Where(t => t.TagName).Contains(searchString).ToList();
            }
        }

        return View(orderedModels);
```

Searching based on the other columns of the code table work fine, I just included them so you could get a better idea of what I am trying to do; maybe there is a better way than doing my if statement to see if the search has matched anything else first. It's just searching on Tags that doesn't seem to be working for me.

The part I need help with:

```
 orderedModels = models.SelectMany(x => x.SelectedTags).Select(t => t).Where(t => t.TagName).Contains(searchString).ToList();
```

Comment: I doubt whether your `if` condition `orderedModels == models.ToList()` would ever evaluate to true. On different note, I am unable to understand what exactly you are trying to do - perhaps you can give an example!

Comment: The example is in the if statement :) I'm trying to query the code table based on the tag entered as a search parameter.

Comment: shouldn't you be then matching search string with tag names and then look up for code files? You seems to be matching with other attributes of `CodeTagViewModel`

Comment: As I posted in the question, my query does not work. There wouldn't be much point in me posting this question if it did. You are more than welcome to post a working answer but I am having trouble getting my head around many to many in Linq.

Comment: I have posted the answer but as I said I couldn't make out purpose of the code that involves `CodeTagViewModel`. Moreover, I have already pointed out that code is never going to enter `if` block so I am not sure if my answer would help you unless you really care to explain what *exactly* you are asking!

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it, I have specified what I am trying to do in the question and again in these comments. The CodeTagViewModel is to allow more than one model to be passed into a single view. The if block works fine as far as I can see, even if it doesn't that is not the issue here (and I did say in the question, if you have a better way of doing it then let me know). It seems like you are trying to answer the question without really knowing what you are doing yourself. I appreciate the sentiment but it's not really going to help either of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
if(orderedModels.Count == 0)
            {
                var codesByTag = db.Code.Where(c => c.Tags.Any(t => t.TagName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString))).ToList<Code>();
                foreach (var searchResult in codesByTag)
                {
                    orderedModels.Add(MapCodeToModel(searchResult));
                }
            }
```

MapCodeToModel is my own self explanatory method that I can post on request if it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a enumeration of tags, you can find code files by directly navigating relation with code files -

```
var tags = ... // enumeration of tags
var matches = tags.SelectMany(t => t.Code);
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your code, I don't understand what exactly you trying to search here but let's say your search string is supposed to match tag name then finding matching tags should be straight-forward:

```
var tags = db.Tags.Where(t => t.TagName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
```

**EDIT**
I don't understand why you need to search against the model. You can search directly against the code:

```
searchString = searchString.ToUpper();
var directMatches = db.Code.Where(c=> c.Title.ToUpper().Contains(searchString) ||
                        c.Description.ToUpper().Contains(searchString) ||    
                        ... (and so on)
```

This would give matching code files on other attributes and then you can union this with matches from tag search to get the consolidated results (`directMatches.Union(matches)`).

On different note, use `ToList` sparingly - it realizes current query to generate in-memory data, so code statement such as

```
List<Code> codes = db.Code.ToList<Code>();
```

This will bring all code rows from database to memory. Similarly, code `if(orderedModels == models.ToList())` will not work because you are comparing two results of `ToList` invocations which would be two different memory lists and reference comparison of them will fail.

Comment: How is the search parameter being used in that query?

Comment: The orderedModels needs to change not the tags. I'm trying to anticipate the user searching anything, so it tries to match based on every column of the code table. That's what the first layer in the if statement is doing. But because the tags associated with each code is the SelectedTags from the tag table (a list of tags rather than just one) I am having trouble with the query.

Comment: Searching against the view model because it is what I need to pass into the view...